# method doesn't get called in Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 classes, ObjectBody(BodyNode) and a UpdateLayer(CCLayer), I've implemented a delegate method to let ObjectBody call a method in UpdateLayer.
Here is the example of my delegate protocol.

In my ObjectBody.h

```
//Here i set up the protocol
@protocol objectDelegate
-(void) updateStatus
@end

//ObjectBody is a BodyNode
@interface ObjectBody:BodyNode{
    id<objectDelegate> delegate
}

@property (nonatomic,assign)id<objectDelegate>delegate;
```

In my ObjectBody.mm

```
//synthesize the property in .h
@synthesize delegate

//sendStatus will get called upon collision
-(void)sendStatus{
[delegate updateStatus]
```

In my UpdateLayer.h

```
@interface UpdateLayer:CCLayer<objectDelegate>{
    ObjectBody *object;
}
```

In my UpdateLayer.mm

```
-(id)init{
    if((self=[super init])){
       object=[[ObjectBody alloc]init];
       [object setDelegate:self]; 
    }
}

-(void)updateStatus{
    //Update something here
}
```

The problem is, the method updateStatus doesn't get called at all. any idea?

Comment: Does sendStatus method execute?

Comment: I agree with Ravin, the first order of business in a case like this is to determine what's getting called. Place some `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));` at the beginning of functions to see what's getting called.

Comment: Yea, i did place NSLOG and sendStatus did get called. That's what i couldn't figure out

Comment: Don't you need to set your delegate with your delegate member variable.  The member variable delegate is never initialized or set as your delegate so wouldn't delegate be nil when [delegate updateStatus] is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

in UpdateLayer init method, should you not retain object ?

Comment: No. Performing alloc init on the ObjectBody class will give you an object with a retain count of 1 already. Sending -retain would only raise the references to two.